# How do I pass a jade variable into a mixin as an argument?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I would like to pass a variable into a mixin and I don't know how.

Here is an example:

```
- var jquery = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"

mixin cdn(location)
   script(src=#{location})

+cdn("#{jquery}")
```

I want it to generate the following line:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try `script(src="!{location}")`

Comment: @Daniel_L Didn't work, comes out like this: `<script src="!{location}"></script>`

Comment: actually i think for jade you can just do `script(src=location)` in the mixin defintion, cant remember off the top of my head for sure

Comment: @Daniel_L I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `+cdn("#{jquery}")` do this:

`+cdn(jquery)`

That will output:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`